# Fiddler setting proxy settings despite process ended

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I have an interesting issue where upon closing fiddler, it still sets my proxy settings. This results in me not being able to access the internet unless I have fiddler open (Due to it reverting my proxy settings once I change them).

Is this a global issue, and if so, does anybody know the process/service that is responsible for this? I'd love to kill it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddler adopts your system proxy settings on start and reverts them when it shuts down. Fiddler doesn't have any components, services, modules, etc, that change anything when it is not actually running.

When Fiddler isn't running, what are the exact settings values seen inside IE's Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings?

Comment: Proxy settings are set to that of fiddler. When changing them, they automatically revert back to fiddlers proxy.

Comment: This indicates that the WinINET broker process is corrupt and it's unable to commit state changes. This is an obscure problem we've seen on one machine in 100000. You should probably contact us using Help > Send Feedback for further troubleshooting. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for confirming Eric. Interestingly though, this occurs on an irregular basis and as such I won't be able to submit it until this occurs. I'll get to it when it does, though!